# problem using WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} in apache configuration

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

im using django with apache and mod_wsgi
i am facing a problem when i use WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} in apache configuration file (.conf) . i dont know if i am using this directive correctly or i need to use it in another way , the problem is that i needed to add this directive to fix a problem for xapian as described in this ticket (http://trac.xapian.org/ticket/185) after that the search started to work but all my sites contents got mixed up, meaning site1 content appears on site2.when i removed WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} , sites are rendering properly again but search stopped working.

here is my .conf file  contents:

```
NameVirtualHost my_ip_address:80
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
<VirtualHost my_ip_address:80>
ServerName www.site1.com
ServerAlias site1

WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/sa/www/site1/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site1/apache">
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /site_media/ "/home/sa/www/site1/media/"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site1/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<VirtualHost my_ip_address:80>
ServerName www.site2.com
ServerAlias site2

WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/sa/www/site2/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site2/apache">
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /site_media/ "/home/sa/www/site2/media/"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site2/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

Alias /media/ "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>



WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

< VirtualHost my_ip_address:80 >
ServerName www.site3.com
ServerAlias site3

WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/sa/www/site3/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site3/apache">
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /site_media/ "/home/sa/www/site3/media/"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site3/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

Alias /media/ "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>


WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<VirtualHost my_ip_address:80>

ServerName www.site4.com
ServerAlias site4

WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/sa/www/site4/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site4/apache"> 
    Allow from all 
</Directory>

Alias /site_media/ "/home/sa/www/site4/media/"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site4/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

Alias /media/ "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>


WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<VirtualHost my_ip_address:80>
ServerName www.site5.com
ServerAlias site5

WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/sa/www/site5/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site5/apache">
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /site_media/ "/home/sa/www/site5/media/"
<Directory "/home/sa/www/site5/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

Alias /media/ "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
<Directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

has anybody faced this issue 
any suggestions

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django's implementation prevents multiple Django instances running in same interpreter (application group). Thus if running multiple Django sites on same Apache server and must set WSGIApplicationGroup to %{GLOBAL}, then you MUST use daemon mode and delegate each Django site to a separate daemon process group. Daemon mode is preferred anyway.

Ensure you read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

The latter explaining part why daemon mode is good as far as making code reloading easier.

Comment: thanks for the links , using daemon mode solved the problem 
but i would like an advice about the parameters for processes,threads how do i decide those numbers

Comment: If your code is thread safe, use the defaults, ie. Don't specify either processes or threads options and let it default to single process with 15 threads. This is usually adequate for most people. In other words, don't try and prematurely optimize things. If you start to see issues with response of specific sites, then maybe will need to tweak for just that daemon process group.