# Request time out with Django and scikit-image

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-ec2, scikit-image

I am developing a webapp for image processing with [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/). Every works fine on both my local machine and on the Amazon EC2 server when I launch the script manually over SSH.

However, when I call my script from Django's views.py every requests fail due to time limit. Basically I launch a request and never get a reply from Django. I am using Apache as web server. I noticed that this happens only if my script import scikit-image, e.g. when I use

```
from skimage import io
```

If I remove all `import` of scikit-image then it works fine (even with dozens of other libraries imported).

Moreover I don't get any error, nor logs so I don't understand where the problem is! Any suggestion?

UPDATE

I tried both the last stable version 0.10.1 and the dev0.11: same problem on both.
I noticed that the problem does not appear if I use `import skimage` or `from skimage import img_as_float, img_as_bool` but it appears with any of the following and many more

```
 skimage.color import rgb2hsv
 from skimage.filter import threshold_adaptive
 from skimage.morphology import  remove_small_objects
```

Comment: Does this only happen when importing the `io` submodule?

Comment: Also, which version of skimage are you using?  Did you also try the latest version from git?

Comment: If I use python -v myscript.py I can see when all the modules are loaded. Is there an equivalent way to log all the imports in Django when a view is called?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem and relative solution.
The problem relies on the interpreter used by mod_wsgi. Apparently some third party packages for Python which use C extension modules, and this includes scikit-image, will only work in the Python main interpreter. See similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819588/using-scipy-stats-stats-in-django-after-deployment).

For future reference I solved the problem by adding the following line to my site .conf file

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Further reference:

- https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API
- [problem using WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} in apache configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405533/problem-using-wsgiapplicationgroup-global-in-apache-configuration)